# go mod unable to find modules

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to build a Docker image using a go compiled binary as the ENTRYPOINT but I'm unable to compile the binary because the go mod is unable to find one of the required files.

the project structure looks like this:

```
editor/
├── container
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── src
│       ├── install-browsers.sh
│       ├── selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
│       └── webCopy
│           ├── go.mod
│           ├── go.sum
│           └── main.go
├── copier
│   ├── copier.go
│   ├── internal
│   │   └── utils.go
│   └── scripts
│       └── load.go
└── resource
    └── handler.go
```

The file I'm trying to compile is webCopy/main.go
Inside that file I need to import the module editor/copier

The path to the editor module is:
bitbucket.org/backend/editor
which is inside the GOPATH

The error the go mod tidy gives me is:

```
go: finding module for package bitbucket.org/mvps/backend/editor/copier
bitbucket.org/backend/editor/container/src/webCopy imports
        bitbucket.org/backend/editor/copier: cannot find module providing package bitbucket.org/mvps/backend/editor/copier: reading https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/mvps/backend?fields=scm: 404 Not Found
```

I really don't want to mix the copier module inside the src of the container, the reason being I feel the submodules to the main should be separated, yet inside the editor module.

Furthermore, I'm using go.mod as a way to get a clean image by compiling main.go and using the binary to create a new clean artifact, so I would like to have the go.mod and go.sum files inside editor/container/src/webCopy/

btw. I have checked the package names and everything is properly named.

Comment: I would compile all the source outside and copy the binary in the image on build or do essentially the same but with multistage build and compiling the code in the first stage container.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, but it adds some overhead during the compile stage...

Comment: Otherwise, you could upload your copier code to git, so you can install it with go mod. In any case, you will need to bring them together to compile.

Comment: Are you actually trying to compile this on build or just like that? Maybe I'm confused by the docker file. If it's outside, did you already try `go install` on the dependencies? IMO they should be available in the system for other packages to use then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI if you are using a `go modules` build - you are no longer using `GOPATH` - so that is not the issue.

If you want a custom build - and not have to create laborious git key access to repo's from within a docker build - you can leverage the [replace directive](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) in `go.mod`

So add to `.../webCopy/go.mod` the following line:

```
replace bitbucket.org/backend/editor/copier => ../../../copier/
```

this will instruct the `go build` to use this relative path (instead of a direct https download)

Comment: @Volker the answer clearly states `GOPATH` is not at play here. The `replace` directive is perfectly acceptable during local development builds. So why isn't it acceptable in a docker build? When that docker image, again, may be used for development purposes?